# How to do multiple PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I admit I am not very good at `PIVOT` (no pun intended) but managed to get half way to what I need but I am stuck at the second part.
So here is my table and some data and also a screen shot of how the data looks right now:
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ([PriceName] VARCHAR(50), [PriceName_Change] VARCHAR(50), [PriceVal] DECIMAL(28, 2), [PriceVal_Change] DECIMAL(28, 2), [Portfolio] NVARCHAR(200), [benchmark] NVARCHAR(200) , [EffectiveDate] DATE);
INSERT INTO #temptable ([PriceName], [PriceName_Change], [PriceVal], [PriceVal_Change], [Portfolio], [benchmark], [EffectiveDate])
VALUES 
 ('OilPrice', 'OilPrice_CHANGE', 1607.00, 3.61, N'PORT45', N'SP500',N'2022-06-02T00:00:00')
,('OilPrice', 'OilPrice_CHANGE', 1607.00, 3.61, N'PORT45', N'SP500',N'2022-06-01T00:00:00')
,('OilPrice', 'OilPrice_CHANGE', 607.00, 12.61, N'PORT45', N'SP500',N'2022-05-31T00:00:00')
```

So `OilPrice` is associated with values from column `PriceVal` and `PriceName_Change` is associated with values from column `PriceVal_Change` and that's the two things I want to PIVOT on.
I managed to write it for one of them but I can't get to write it for both of them.
Here is what I did:

```
SELECT
    portfolio
  , EffectiveDate
  , [OilPrice]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
             SM.portfolio
           , SM.PriceVal
           , SM.PriceName
           , SM.EffectiveDate
        FROM #temptable SM
    ) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    SUM(PriceVal)
    FOR PriceName IN ([OilPrice])
) AS pvt;
```

Below is how I am **expecting** the result to show:

```
OilPrice | OilPrice_Change | Portfolio | Benchmark | EffectiveDate |
1607.00  | 3.61            | PORT45    | SP500     | 2022-06-02    |
1607.00  | 3.61            | PORT45    | SP500     | 2022-06-01    |
607.00   | 12.61           | PORT45    | SP500     | 2022-05-31    |
```

Comment: Expected results would help

Comment: Please include the exact expected result for the sample data you included.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks, updated my question with a sample of the expected result at the bottom.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks, updated my question with a sample of the expected result at the bottom.

Comment: What is the (unintended) pun?

Comment: @MartinSmith : Pivoting

Answer (score 3):

Your expected results are the last 5 columns of the table, so there is no need for any pivoting.

All you have to do is filter the table so that you get only the rows with `PriceName = 'OilPrice'` and `PriceName_Change = 'OilPrice_CHANGE'` and rename the columns `PriceVal` to `OilPrice` and `PriceVal_Change` to `OilPrice_Change`:

```
SELECT PriceVal AS OilPrice, 
       PriceVal_Change AS OilPrice_Change, 
       Portfolio, benchmark, EffectiveDate
FROM #temptable
WHERE PriceName = 'OilPrice' AND PriceName_Change = 'OilPrice_CHANGE';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2c389f3fbf0e10a19023e84565ed7f69).

Comment: well, what if are 20 more rows ? in my example it was OilPrice in a row but let's say other rows like RussiaWar , Floods, EarthQuake, MarketCrash, etc are also in that table.

Comment: @UnskilledCoder what is your expected output in this case?

Comment: New columns, exactly similar to how OilPrice and OilPrice_Change resulted in new columns for the output , now let's say Floods will also result in Floods and Floods_Change columns.

Comment: @UnskilledCoder does this mean that the resultset will have all columns OilPrice, OilPrice_Change, Floods, Floods_Change,  RussiaWar, RussiaWar_Change, etc from which only 2 will have values in each row and the rest will be null?

Comment: you got the column names right. But no not null,  they will have values too, they get their values from PriceVal and PriceVal_Chage  column.

Comment: @UnskilledCoder post sample data and **expected results** here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017 to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear exactly how you want to aggregate (does it make sense to sum a `Change` value?). Also unclear is what result you want if there are other types of changes.

But you can use conditional aggregation like this

```sql
SELECT
  OilPrice = SUM(CASE WHEN PriceName = 'OilPrice' THEN PriceVal END), 
  OilPrice_CHANGE = SUM(CASE WHEN PriceName = 'OilPrice' THEN PriceVal_Change END),
  t.Portfolio,
  t.benchmark,
  t.EffectiveDate
FROM #temptable t
GROUP BY
  t.Portfolio,
  t.benchmark,
  t.EffectiveDate;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=25641a9d15243da5df95ad4b98ad74d3)

Comment: I don't need a "sum" , I just need it to show the value. But looking at PIVOT docs I saw they were always using some mort of sum, avg , min, max etc so I used one.

Comment: My column naming was bad, instead of PriceName or PriceName_Change if you think of RiskName and RiskName_Change then it makes more sense. Like Oil Price is a risk in market , then another one could be Russia's War another "RiskName" etc

Comment: Pivot is inherently conditional aggregation. T-SQL doesn't have an `ANY` function, you need to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an UNPIVOT and then PIVOT that object. This is just a guess, because I don't know what you want the final output to look like, but maybe...

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (select PriceName, Portfolio, benchmark, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), PriceVal) AS [PriceVal],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), PriceName_Change) AS [PriceName_Change]from temptable) 
as PVT
UNPIVOT
(
  Item for Items in (PriceVal, PriceName_Change)
) AS unpvt
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help but no not like that. I added a sample of expected results to my question at the bottom.  That's how I am trying to get it to look . Thanks.